# Show child data in a DataGridView control related to multiple parent entity records

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a VB winforms form with three `BindingSource` controls, each showing data (via `DataGridView`s or bound textboxes) from three related entities that were created DB First.

I need to have a `datagridview` showing & allowing adding/editing/deleting only `tbl_Distribution_DealerModel_OverAlts` records that are related to both the current `tbl_PrimaryDealerGroup` record (joining on fields `tbl_PrimaryDealerGroup.DealerGroupID = tbl_Distribution_DealerModels_OverAlts.FirstDealerGroupID`) and the current `tbl_SeriesManufacturer` record (joining on two common fields: `aus_series_cde` and `ManufacturerID`).  `tbl_Distribution_DealerModel_OverAlts` is on the many-side of the relationships to the two other tables:

[image: Entities]

How can I have a child entity's `datagridview` show only records that are related to each of two (or more) parent entity records?  It may also be necessary for me to relate a child entity to three or more parents in this project, so generically applicable answers would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sorted this out myself:

```
Private Sub bs_tblSM_tblPDG_CurrentChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles bs_tbl_Series_Manufacturer.CurrentChanged, bs_tbl_PrimaryDealerGroup.CurrentChanged
    If bs_tbl_Series_Manufacturer.Current IsNot Nothing And bs_tbl_PrimaryDealerGroup.Current IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim Series As String = bs_tbl_Series_Manufacturer.GetItemProperties(Nothing)("aus_series_cde").GetValue(bs_tbl_Series_Manufacturer.Current)
        Dim Manufacturer As Byte = bs_tbl_Series_Manufacturer.GetItemProperties(Nothing)("ManufacturerID").GetValue(bs_tbl_Series_Manufacturer.Current)
        Dim PDG As Integer = bs_tbl_PrimaryDealerGroup.GetItemProperties(Nothing)("DealerGroupID").GetValue(bs_tbl_PrimaryDealerGroup.Current)
        Dim ChangeFilter As Boolean = False
        If m_CurrentSeries <> Series Then
            m_CurrentSeries = Series
            ChangeFilter = True
        End If
        If m_CurrentManufacturer <> Manufacturer Then
            m_CurrentManufacturer = Manufacturer
            ChangeFilter = True
        End If
        If m_CurrentPDG <> PDG Then
            m_CurrentPDG = PDG
            ChangeFilter = True
        End If
        If ChangeFilter Then
            Dim DlrMdlOverAlts As IEnumerable(Of tbl_Distribution_DealerModel_OverAlts)
            DlrMdlOverAlts = From DDMOA As tbl_Distribution_DealerModel_OverAlts In m_Context.tbl_Distribution_DealerModel_OverAlts.Local.ToBindingList _
                             Where DDMOA.aus_series_cde = m_CurrentSeries And DDMOA.ManufacturerID = m_CurrentManufacturer And DDMOA.FirstDealerGroupID = m_CurrentPDG _
                             Select DDMOA
            bs_tbl_Distribution_DealerModel_OverAlts.DataSource = DlrMdlOverAlts.ToList
            Me.dgvtbcDealerModelOverAlts_aus_series_cde.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = m_CurrentSeries.ToString
            Me.dgvtbcDealerModelOverAlts_ManufacturerID.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = m_CurrentManufacturer.ToString
            Me.dgvtbcDealerModelOverAlts_FirstDealerGroupID.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = m_CurrentPDG.ToString
            bs_tbl_Distribution_DealerModel_OverAlts.ResetBindings(False)
            ChangeFilter = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The trick was to not try to use `DataMember`s of parent `BindingSource`s in the child `BindingSource`, but to relate the entities in code in the `CurrentChanged` of both parent `BindingSource`s.